# Using css only, Add css style to the parent(without .second-stage class) of .apply-style-here

Tags: html, css

How can i apply style to the parent div of .apply-style-here the styles by meeting only this condition

1. Parent of .apply-style-here should be a plain div or without the .second-stage class
2. .apply-style-here parent's parent should not have a .second-stage
   Thank you

```
<div class="first-stage">
    <div>
        <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="first-stage">
    <div class="second-stage">
        <div>
            <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tried solution

```
/* Result: Put border to all parent of apply-style-here class */
.first-stage:has(div > .apply-style-here) > div {
/*  margin-top: 20px; */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Result: No styles applied at all */
.first-stage:not('div > .second-stage') > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* Result: No styles applied at all */
.first-stage:has(div:not('.second-stage') > .apply-style-here) > div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* Result: Applied to all .apply-style-here even second .second-stage is present */
.first-stage:has(div:not(.second-stage) > .apply-style-here) > div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
/* Result: Applied to all .apply-style-here even second .second-stage is present */

.first-stage:has(div:not(.second-stage > .apply-style-here)) > div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: hello, can you clarify a bit your conditions ? 1. plain without .second-stage so it can have any other class or not any at all or is it about the structure  ?  2. so here we have a structure of 4 divs without any class named .second-stage . | note that :has() is not yet supported by FF https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description, this following selector could work:

```
:not(.second-stage) > :not(.second-stage) > .apply-style-here
```

```css
:not(.second-stage) > :not(.second-stage) > .apply-style-here {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-stage">
    <div>
        <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="first-stage">
    <div class="second-stage">
        <div>
            <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as commented , selector `:has()` is not yet supported everywhere . https://caniuse.com/css-has

Aside, some your `:not()` selector rules could be rewritten via the `[class="xclass"]` instead `'.xclass'`

your style sheet could be rewrite :

```css
/* extra gaps for demo */
div{margin:0.15em;border:solid;}

/* Result: Put border to all parent of apply-style-here class*/
.first-stage:has(.apply-style-here) div:not([class]) {
  border: 1px solid gold;
} 

/* Result: No styles applied at all */
.first-stage > :not([class="second-stage"]) div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Result: No styles applied at all */
.first-stage:has(div:not([class="second-stage"]) > .apply-style-here) > div {
    border: 1px solid purple;
}

/* Result: Applied to all .apply-style-here even second .second-stage is present */
.first-stage:has(div:not([class="second-stage"]) > .apply-style-here)  {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
/* Result: Applied to all .apply-style-here even second .second-stage is present */

.first-stage:has(div:not([class="second-stage"] > .apply-style-here)) > div {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

@supports not selector( div:has(div)) {
body::before {content:'Selector :has()\0D\0A Not Supported in your browser,\0D\0A use another browser for testing.';display:block;text-align:center;background:yellow;padding:0.25em;color:crimson;font-size:2em;white-space:pre;}
}
```

```html
<div class="first-stage">
  <div>
    <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first-stage">
  <div class="second-stage">
    <div>
      <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="apply-style-here">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

online demo you can fork and edit https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QWJWbpG